# java.lang.InstantiationException: class has no zero argument constructor

Tags: java, android

При вызове

```
public void onPress(int primaryCode) {
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,swipe.class));
}
```

вылезает данная ошибка.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lol.keyboard/com.example.lol.keyboard.swipe}: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.example.lol.keyboard.swipe> has no zero argument constructor
```

swipe.class:

```
public class swipe extends View {


public swipe(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    float touchX = event.getX();
    float touchY = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction())
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            MainActivity.coord.add(touchX);
            MainActivity.coord.add(touchY);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: А вопрос в чём? И в тексте ошибки явно говорится о том, что в классе `swipe` (название которого почему-то начинается с маленькой буквы) нет конструктора без параметров. Соответственно, либо создайте в классе `swipe` такой конструктор, либо не используйте данный код. И класс всё же стоит назвать `Swipe`.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь запустить класс `com.example.lol.keyboard.swipe` как `Activity` , хотя на самом деле он наследник `View`. Уж определитесь что Вам нужно - стартовать активность или куда-то всунуть виджет

Answer (score 1):

Методом `startActivity` можно запустить только активити, т.е. классы, наследующие `Activity` или `AppCompatActivity`. У вас же класс наследует `View`, который не наследует актвити.

Если вам таки надо активити запустить, то унаследуйте класс от него и уберите все конструкторы - у активити и фрагментов они используются системой и не должны никак меняться разработчиком